# iOS in-app purchase item not returned in products but only in invalidProductIdentifiers in sandbox. How to debug?

Tags: ios4, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am adding in-app purchasing to my app.  I have followed all the steps that Apple outlines here (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html  see Q&A #6 especially) as well as in the In-App Programming Guide.

The problem is that when I send a product request in during testing on my test iPod Touch, the response shows it in the invalidProductIdentifiers and not a valid product.

My App does have a specific non wild card App ID.

My profile I am using to sign the app has the App ID explicitly in it and does not use a wild card.

The in-app purchase item is a standard non-consumable non-subscription item (enabling enhanced functionality).  I added it in the store as an in-app item for my app.  It has been set to be cleared for sale.  (It is at state "waiting for screen shot upload").

I copied and pasted the in-app item id from iTunes Connect and pasted it into my app to make sure that I did not spell anything wrong.

I have searched on StackOverflow and using Bing and Google for clues on how to diagnose this problem and basically all the answers were to check the app id, item id, signing profile, etc.

No error is being returned and the product request successfully completes so there is no NSError object to query.

How can one diagnose the problem and debug this?

Thanks

Comment: somehow in ios5 I can read the sandboxed in-app purchase, and I will get bug reports for ios4 :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One thing to check that you didn't mention: Did you install the build by running from Xcode with your device connected via USB? You can't connect to the sandbox store using an ad hoc deployment.

If you haven't already, take a look at [Troy Brandt's exhaustive list of invalid product ID issues](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll take a look.  Yes, it is being installed from XCode run command and over USB and being actively debugged in gdb (ie I see my NSLog stuff in gdb console and can set a breakpoint if necessary).

Comment: OK, the link you gave gave me the hint to delete the app off of my device.  That seems to have fixed things.  I don't know why but it is now working just fine thanks to the info in your link.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the app. It worked instantly in my case!

Answer (score 0):

I just found a quick way to solve the invalid product ID problem, at least to my case after I've tried  Troy Brandt's exhaustive list of invalid product ID issues, but still get 2 invalid product ids out of 4. The solution is to delete all IAP and restart with different IAPs, withe brand new reference IDs and product IDs, then I deleted the app in testing device. After these, everything worked. Apple should be shamed to make IAP so difficult to implement.